# Is <article> okay for truncated posts?

Tags: html, semantic-markup, article

I'm making a Tumblr theme (hold your criticism) and I'd like to use some semantic tags (since this seems to be something most themes don't have.) The way these blogs are styled is a main page full of posts that may be truncated, and may not be. You can then click a link and get a permalink to that post, or the full post if it's truncated.

**I want to use `<article>` for these posts on the main page, but I don't know if it's okay to put a truncated post in an `<article>` tag.** I'd guess it'd be okay since the RSS feed could supply a link to the full article, but then would the full article also use `<article>` tags? Is `<section>` more applicable, even though some posts are perfectly fit for syndication?

Comment: What difference do you expect it to make whether you use `article` or something else (such as `section` or `div`)? The question does not show any example of what the real structure and content might be. So it is difficult to decide whether this is “unclear what you asking” or “primarily opinion-based”.

Comment: @Orangestar: I edited a lot your question to try to express in less words and more precisely what I think you mean. Feel free to revert it.

Comment: What example do you need? All the Question should contain, the asker has written. He means those Articles, whiches has normaly a Button or Link "Read More"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation, [`article`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/sections.html#the-article-element) *(bold is from me)*:

> The article element represents a complete, **or self-contained**, composition in a document, page, application, or site and that is, in principle, independently distributable or reusable, e.g. in syndication. This could be a forum post, a magazine or newspaper article, a blog entry, a user-submitted comment, an interactive widget or gadget, or any other independent item of content.

So `article` represents not only complete, but self-contained composition in document too, as bolded above, that means, truncated posts fits `article` element too.

[`section`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/sections.html#the-section-element) on the other hand *(bold is from me)*:

> The section element represents a **generic section** of a document or application. A section, in this context, is a thematic grouping of content. The theme of each section should be identified, typically by including a heading (h1-h6 element) as a child of the section element.

So `section` should not include posts or their fragments directly.

Comment: I agree with your conclusion about `article`, but I disagree with your conlusion about `section`: The sectioning elements `article`/`aside`/`nav` are just **more specific** `section` elements. So whenever you use on of them, you could also use the "generic" `section` element instead (of course you should always use the most specific element, so choosing `article` over `section` is correct here, but it would not be "incorrect" to use `section`.).

Comment: Unor makes a good point. So since the `<article>` could be perfectly self-contained if the truncation is in the correct place, then it would count for `<article>` I suppose. `<section>` would just imply it's not a part of the "meat" of the page.