# Should I use <article> for blog post previews?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I'm making a view which will show a list of blog posts, with small excerpts of each. Is  the correct semantic element to use?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895214/what-is-the-semantically-correct-way-to-use-the-article-tag-in-html-5-with

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is <article> okay for truncated posts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23692612/is-article-okay-for-truncated-posts)

Answer (score 2):

For small excerpts, both `article` and `section` are OK.

Quoted from [html spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-article-element):

> The **article** element represents a **complete**, or self-contained, composition in a document, page, application, or site and that is, in principle, **independently** distributable or reusable, e.g. in syndication. This could be a forum post, a magazine or newspaper article, **a blog entry**, a user-submitted comment, an interactive widget or gadget, or any other independent item of content.

Note that:

> Authors are encouraged to use the **article** element instead of the **section** element when it would make sense to syndicate the contents of the element.

Answer (score 1):

I would use it like this for each adding a header and a footer too

```
<article>
<header>
<h1>Apple</h1>
<p>Published: <time>2009-10-09</time></p>
</header>
<p>The <b>apple</b> is the pomaceous fruit of the apple tree...</p>
 <footer>
<p><small>Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike License</small></p>
</footer>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

> The key point here is that the content has to make sense independent of its context, i.e. when all the surrounding content is stripped away.

[Soruce](http://html5doctor.com/the-article-element/)

An example is:

```
<article>
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <p>Text</p>
</article>
```

**So each blog-post preview can be an article element.**